# WLS 12.2.1.3 ConnectException

Tags: weblogic, java-web-start, java-9

I have a WLS 12c (12.2.1.3) Instance, which runs on Java 9. Additional i have also a webstart application (Java 9). Both runs on localhost. I can start the application without problems but when i want to connect as an user, i will become a exception

```
java.net.ConnectException: t3://127.0.0.1:7001: Bootstrap to: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:7001' over: 't3' got an error or timed out while trying to connect to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:7001
javax.security.auth.login.LoginException: java.net.ConnectException: t3://127.0.0.1:7001: Bootstrap to: 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:7001' over: 't3' got an error or timed out while trying to connect to 127.0.0.1/127.0.0.1:7001
```

I listen to adress 127.0.0.1 with default port 7001 in my weblogic Instance. How can i solve the problem?

Comment: WLS 12.2.1.3 is not supported with java 9.

Comment: Java 9 is unsupported for WLS 12.2.1.3 or for Webstart Application?

Comment: for WLS 12.2.1.3

Answer (score 0):

In the admin console, please check the listen address. If the listen address is set to say `hostname`, you will need to connect to `hostname` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

@Emmanuel is right, it appears that 12.2.1.3 does not support Java 9. Although I doubt this issue is directly related to Java 9.